# calling methods of a class inherited form an interface and another ancestor

Tags: delphi, oop, interface, multiple-inheritance

I have problem with implementing relation between some classes. I got three different classes serving three different forms. All these classes speak in same language, so they are inherited from same class called `TAncestorServer`. Let’s call its descendants `TForm1Server`, `TForm2Server`, and `TForm3Server`. `TAncestorServer` contains an abstract method called `Function1`, so `TForm1`, `TForm2`, and `TForm3` can call it with no problem through their own classes inherited from it, they have an access to the classes through a property named `Server`. But the problem is about another form called `TForm4`! It’s very similar to other forms but it’s not independent like them. It works with `TForm2Server` or `TForm3Server`. Still not a problem, but imagine another method like `Function2` which is declared in `TForm2Server` and `TForm3Server`, `TForm4` needs to call them. I can go like this:

```
if Server is TForm2Server then
   TForm2Server(Server).Function2
else if Server is TForm3Server then
  TForm3Server(Server).Function2;
```

But it can turn in an infinite if-else clause! So I thought something like multiple-inheritance may help here. I declared an interface called `IForm4Server` which contains `Function2`. So `TForm2Server` and `TForm3Server` inherit from both `TAncestorServer` and `IForm4Server`. I thought something like this could work:

```
If Server is IForm4Server then
  IForm4Server(Server).Function2;
```

But compiler doesn’t think so, it says that  it’s not a valid type cast, because `TAncestorServer` is not `IForm4Server`, which is absolutely right. `TForm1Server` has no idea about implementing `Function2` and has to leave it blank. I can’t declare `TForm4.Server` as `IForm4Server` too, because `Function1` represents a huge number of methods and properties, however I still can’t type cast `IForm4Server` to `TAncestorServer`.

As a solution I can define two different properties in `TForm4` like `GeneralServer: TAncestorServer` and `Form4Server: IForm4Server` and then assign same instance of `TForm2Server` or `TForm3Server` to them, but I don’t feel good about it. How should I do this? Is there any standard pattern for it?

Comment: About the title of your question, a Interface is not an ancestor of your class. Delphi supports single-inheritance only (as you seem to know), so every class have only one father/grand father.. and so on. 

So, you only inherit methods from the ancestor. 

Your class can _implement_ any number of interfaces, but the interfaces are not ancestors of your class, just interfaces it implements.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I’m new in both using interfaces and asking questions in English! Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implementing one or many interfaces is the correct approach, but looks like you're a bit confused about the proper syntax and have no experience with interfaces.

Basic things are:

- You have a common ancestor class (or form) for any number of classes. The ancestor declares virtual methods that the classes specialize in some way.
- Declare a Interface with any number of methods. Don't forget to add a GUID to your interface.
- Extend your form declarations to implement the declared Interface, adding the Interface to the class declaration and adding the declared methods.
- You now can:

  - Polymorphically call any virtual method using the ancestor class
  - Ask any form if it implements a interface, and if it does, retrieve a interface reference to it and call any interface method.  All this can be done using the [supports](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SysUtils.Supports) function.

I made the most simple example I can think off, using visual inheritance for forms and a simple interface. The extracts of the example follows:

#### The common ancestor class:

```
type
  TServerForm = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure Method1; virtual;
  end;
```

#### The interface:

```
type
  IMyInterface = interface
  ['{B7102C7E-F7F6-492A-982A-4C55CB1065B7}']
    procedure Method2;
  end;
```

#### The child forms:

This one inherits from the TServerForm and implements the interface

```
type
  TServerForm3 = class(TServerForm, IMyInterface)
  public
    procedure Method1; override;
    procedure Method2;
  end;
```

This one just inherits from TServerForm

```
type
  TServerForm4 = class(TServerForm)
  public
    procedure Method1; override;
  end;
```

and this one inherits directly from TForm and implements the interface

```
type
  TNoServerForm = class(TForm, IMyInterface)
  public
    procedure Method2;
  end;
```

All the forms are auto-created and then, I have this code to call the methods on a couple of `OnClick` for buttons on another form (the main form of the application example):

To call the virtual method based on polymorphism:

```
procedure TForm6.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to Screen.FormCount - 1 do
  begin
    if (Screen.Forms[I] is TServerForm) then
      TServerForm(Screen.Forms[I]).Method1;
  end;
end;
```

To call the method based on the implementation of the interface:

```
procedure TForm6.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  Intf: IMyInterface;
begin
  for I := 0 to Screen.FormCount - 1 do
  begin
    if Supports(Screen.Forms[I], IMyInterface, Intf) then
      Intf.Method2;
  end;
end;
```

The methods just show messages, and everything works fine:

```
procedure TServerForm3.Method2;
begin
  ShowMessage(ClassName + '.Method2');
end;
```

Comment: +1. Nicely written and the code snippets clearly show the difference.

Comment: No problem. :-) Two minor spelling fixes and a really minor in-line code formatting fix.